# Filenet - Get current date & Time in Filenet Workflow

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-process-engine

I am using Default step Processor in Filenet(5.2.1) and I created a Data Field as "DueDate" of type Time and I initialized it to adddays(systemtime(),14) because I want DueDate to be set 2 weeks after by default. I want this Property to be displayed at Workflow Launch Page but its not working. I also tried to use F_StartTime but that did not work either. Can you please suggest any solution to get current date & Time Or only current date that can be displayed on Workflow Launch page?

FYI, I want DueDate to be displayed at WF Launch page because I want to give the ability to user to change the due date if he/she wants.

Comment: I know the post is old. Did you add the date field to selected parms list in the launch step? This way it will be shown on the launch page

Comment: @ManjunathaMuniyappa : Yes, I added it to selected parms list to display it on launch page but I am looking for a way to have it set to 2 weeks after by default on launch page.

Comment: Then you need to set that exclusively. How are you launching the workflow?

Comment: I have Enabled Manual Launch on subscription. So the users are launching the workflow when they are ready.

Comment: you can do that. Please see the answer section

Answer (score 0):

Steps to get the custom date in launch screen

1. Create a data field say Date. In the expression column, use adddays(systemtime(), 2)
2. Add this field i.e. Date to the selected parameters on the Launch step.
3. Validate and transfer the workflow
4. When workflow is launched, you will see the Date field having future date value. Ex: If you launch the workflow @ 4/17/2019 10:50 AM, Date field will have value 4/19/2019 10:50 AM

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Manjunatha.. I tried that before and here comes the interesting part. If you have created it today(04/17) you will see the date as 04/19 on launch page but if you launch the same workflow tomorrow on 04/18, you will still get the launch date as 04/19 because systemtime() method gets the date when the workflow is transferred not when the workflow is launched.

Comment: That's interesting and I doubt it. Let me try that tomorrow in my workflow and see the behavior.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGLW6_5.5.0/com.ibm.p8.pe.user.doc/bpfe025.htm

Comment: Well that makes sense... so are your users launching worfklow from ICN or workplace? If it's through ICN, See if you can use EDS to set the date